# i'm confused on how to use array merge in a foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, foreach, array-merge

Here's my function:

```
function addr($dfcode)
        {
        return sql::results("select
              A.CODE_,
              case when b.id is null then a.ADDRESS1 else b.addr1 as Address1,
              case when b.id is null then a.ADDRESS2 else b.addr2 as Address2,
              case when b.id is null then a.CITY else b.city as City,
              case when b.id is null then a.STATE_ else b.state as State,
              case when b.id is null then a.ZIP else b.zip as Zip,
              case when b.id is null then a.PHONE else b.phone as Phone,
              case when b.id is null then a.FAX else b.fax as Fax
        from ARE.ADS.DFE a
        left outer join (
              select
                    *
              from ent.dbo.patient_data a
              inner join ent.dbo.doctor_alt_address b on a.doctor_address_id = b.id
              where a.CODE_ =" . $this->patient->hex . "
              and b.doctor_id =" . hexstr($dfcode) . "
              )b on a.CODE_ = b.doctor_id
        where a.CODE_=" . hexstr($dfcode));
        }
```

I need to array merge the above function into the foreach loop. I'm uncertain on how to do this and i'm really new to array_merge. Below i'm pulling all the doctors information that i need to build a form.

Above is a case where the doctor has an alternate address and that needs to be used if in the array merge if a.doctor_address_id = b.id from the criteria above.

```
$p->customForm()->log_creation($docname);   

$doctor = new \CRM\Doctor($p->customForm()->dfcode($docname));

foreach ($doctor->getVars() as $k => $v)
    {
    $data['doctor_'. $k] = $v;
    }

foreach ($patient->get_data() as $k=>$v)
    {
    if (is_string($v) || is_numeric($v))
        $data["patient_" . $k] = strtoupper($v);
    }
```

I hope it's not to confusing, any help would be really appreciated. I hope it's not to vague either. Thank you.

var_dump for $data

```
Array
(
    [employee] => person
    [date] => 05/08/2013
    [datetime] => 05/08/2013 9:41:15 AM
    [department] => stuff
    [employee_ext] => 7457
    [employee_email] => 
    [barcode] => *NZS01*
    [doctor_df_code] => 09HQ
    [doctor_npi] => 1111111111
    [doctor_dea] => B4574
    [doctor_upin] => 
    [doctor_license] => 
    [doctor_phone] => (111)111-1111
    [doctor_fax] => (000)000-0000
    [doctor_fname] => UNDEFINED
    [doctor_lname] => UNDEFINED
    [doctor_title] => 
    [doctor_intake_rx_caller_id] => 
    [doctor_costco_rx_caller_id] => 
    [doctor_reorder_rx_caller_id] => 
    [doctor_address1] => 24 CABELL st
    [doctor_address2] => SUITE 10
    [doctor_city] => places
    [doctor_state] => CA
    [doctor_zip] => 91111
    [doctor_active_events] => 
    [doctor_dont_call] => 0
    [doctor_dont_fax] => 1
)
```

Here's the print var for addr()

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CODE_] => 09HQ
            [doctor_address1] => alternate addy
            [doctor_address2] => 45854
            [doctor_city] => different city
            [doctor_state] => CA
            [doctor_zip] => 963545
            [doctor_phone] => (619)111-2548
            [doctor_fax] => (157)123-4569
        )

)
```

if there is an alternate address i need to overwrite it with the array merge addr()

Comment: So where are you trying to do an array_merge?  I don't see that at all within your code examples. I also have no idea as to how the first code example relates to the second.

Comment: i want to array merge the function addr($dfcode) after $data.

Comment: So what is the problem then?  What results are you getting when you try to merge arrays?  What results are you expecting?  It would actually be more useful in this case to remove all your code and show var_dumps of the array you are trying to merge, along with you code where you are actually trying to merge.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do move the function into the loop. I'll post my current var dump.

Comment: @MikeBrant, updated with the var_dumps